# Вертикально объединить два изображения с разными размерами C#

Tags: c#, изображения, imagemagick

Есть два изображения: `shapka.jpg` и `poster.jpg`
Нужно их объединить так, чтобы шапка была сверху, а постер снизу, сразу под ней. При этом, надо учесть, что шапка первоначально имеет размер **500x71**.
 Постер по ширине никогда *не бывает больше* **500**, но может быть *меньше*. Соответственно, если по ширине он меньше, то и ширину шапки надо пропорционально с высотой подогнать под ширину постера. Подскажите, как это правильно сделать?

В проекте есть библиотека `ImageMagick`, но я не разобрался, как с ее помощью можно такое сделать, поэтому нашел немного другой метод и слегка переделал его под себя:

```
public static Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image firstImage, Image secondImage) // firstImage - shapka.jpg, secondImage - poster.jpg
{
    if (firstImage == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("firstImage");
    }

    if (secondImage == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("secondImage");
    }

    int outputImageWidth = 0;

    if (firstImage.Width > secondImage.Width)
    {
        outputImageWidth = secondImage.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        outputImageWidth = firstImage.Width;
    }

    int outputImageHeight = firstImage.Height + secondImage.Height + 1;

    Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Rectangle(new Point(), firstImage.Size),
                new Rectangle(new Point(), firstImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, firstImage.Height + 1), secondImage.Size),
                new Rectangle(new Point(), secondImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);               
    }

    return outputImage;
}
```

Но здесь картинка не изменяет свой размер, а просто обрезается, что не совсем есть хорошо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С указанной Вами библиотекой я не имею чести быть знакомым, так что привожу простенькое решение, исходя из стандартных инструментов

---

В Вашем коде нигде и не указано масштабирование изображений, а метод [Graphics.DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx), который Вы применяли,

> рисует заданную часть указанного объекта Image в заданном месте, используя заданный размер.

Так что ничего удивительного в том, что изображения обрезались, нет)

Для того, чтобы изображение было отмасштабировано, а не обрезано, Вам следует использовать [конструктор Bitmap(Image, Size)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0wh0045z(v=vs.110).aspx), который

> инициализирует новый экземпляр `Bitmap` из указанного существующего изображения, **масштабированного** до заданного размера.

---

Итак, привожу решение с комментариями:

```
public static Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image firstImage, Image secondImage)
{
    // Проверяем, меньше ли ширина первого изображения, чем второго 
    // (Попутно проверяем на null)
    if ((firstImage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("firstImage")).Width < (secondImage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("secondImage")).Width)
        // Масштабируем второе изображение
        secondImage = ResizeImgByWidth(secondImage, firstImage.Width);
    else
        // Эта проверка на случай равенства ширины изображений
        if (firstImage.Width > secondImage.Width)
            // Масштабируем первое изображение
            firstImage = ResizeImgByWidth(firstImage, secondImage.Width);

    // Создаем Bitmap с шириной картинок (на данном шаге они уже точно равны) и их суммарной высотой
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(firstImage.Width, firstImage.Height + secondImage.Height);

    // Создаем Graphics из заданного изображения
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        // Отрисовываем первую картинку в верхнем левом углу
        g.DrawImage(firstImage, new Point(0, 0));
        // Отрисовываем вторую картинку под первой
        g.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(0, firstImage.Height));
    }
    return result;
}

// Пропорционально изменяем размер изображения по указанной ширине
private static Bitmap ResizeImgByWidth(Image Img, int NewWidth) => new Bitmap(Img, new Size(NewWidth, (int)(Img.Height * (NewWidth / (double)Img.Width))));
```

Проверим:

```
MergeTwoImages(Image.FromFile("test0.png"), Image.FromFile("test1.png")).Save("done.png");
```

И получим на выходе такое изображение
*(чтобы не засорять пост, привожу только результат, разные картинки в нем видны явно)*:
[image: тест0]

---

Собственно, я не удержался от того, чтобы сделать решение адаптивным для любого числа изображений на входе)

Получилось так:

```
public static Bitmap MergeImages(params Image[] Images)
{
    // Проверка на пустоту упакованного массива
    if (Images == null || Images.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("`Images` can't be empty!", "Images");

    // Получаем минимальную ширину, на которую позже будем ориентироваться
    // (Попутно проверяем изображения на null)
    int minWidth = Images.OrderBy(x => (x ?? throw new NullReferenceException()).Width).First().Width;

    // Получаем коллекцию отмасштабированных изображений
    IEnumerable<Image> resized = Images.Select(x => x.Width > minWidth ? ResizeImgByWidth(x, minWidth) : x);

    // Создаем Bitmap с минимальной шириной и суммарной высотой результирующих картинок
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(minWidth, resized.Sum(x => x.Height));

    // Создаем Graphics из заданного изображения
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        int currentHeight = 0;
        foreach (Image img in resized)
        {
            // Отрисовываем текущую картинку, увеличивая шаг на ее высоту
            g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, currentHeight));
            currentHeight += img.Height;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Пропорционально изменяем размер изображения по указанной ширине
private static Bitmap ResizeImgByWidth(Image Img, int NewWidth) => new Bitmap(Img, new Size(NewWidth, (int)(Img.Height * (NewWidth / (double)Img.Width))));
```

Проверим:

```
MergeImages(Image.FromFile("test0.png"), Image.FromFile("test1.png"), Image.FromFile("test2.png")).Save("done.png");
```

Результат:

[image: тест1]

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ смог Вам помочь!
Удачи в Ваших делах)